# Spamassassin does not work with virtual emails

Tags: postfix, email-server, spamassassin, amavis

I have a mailserver running with postfix/spamassassin/amavis/dovecot/mysql... under debian squeeze and all seems to work fine, except one thing: Email forwarder (virtual aliases) never gets scanned by SA. To clearify the problem: I don't want SA to scan the email in the first place when sent to the alias but when it gets delivered to the final local mailbox.

However, the X-Virus-Scanned Header is always added - regardless of virtual aliases or not. So it seems that SA is bypassed but not virusscanning.

I've looked through all config files but have no glue where to change this behaviour. All regular emails sent from the outside and the trusted networks gets scanned and have the appropriate X-SPAM headers.

Any ideas or sugestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, your policy banks in the amavis configuration is not correct. Or at least not appropriate for your setup.

Comment: OK, thx, I'll read the policy banks doc later... calmly ;)